# Spring security saml

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I'm trying to configure spring security saml in my project.

I found spring-security-saml-dsl using spring boot.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can i convert Java-Based Configuration to Spring XML-based from the example (without spring boot):

```
        package com.example.demo;

        import static org.springframework.security.extensions.saml2.config.SAMLConfigurer.saml;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
        @EnableWebSecurity
        @Configuration
        @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
        public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
            @Value("${security.saml2.metadata-url}")
            String metadataUrl;
            @Value("${server.ssl.key-alias}")
            String keyAlias;
            @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
            String password;
            @Value("${server.port}")
            String port;
            @Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
            String keyStoreFilePath;
            @Override
            protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .apply(saml())
                        .serviceProvider()
                            .keyStore()
                                .storeFilePath("saml/keystore.jks")
                                .password(this.password)
                                .keyname(this.keyAlias)
                                .keyPassword(this.password)
                                .and()
                            .protocol("https")
                            .hostname(String.format("%s:%s", "localhost", this.port))
                            .basePath("/")
                            .and()
                        .identityProvider()
                        .metadataFilePath(this.metadataUrl);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm also working on integrating Spring Security SAML DSL library (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml-dsl) for Service Provider (SP). I think there is no point in converting the Java DSL based configuration to XML based configuration as the former one is the latest and allegiant way of configuring SAML. If you want to use the traditional XML based configuration, you can use one of the former Spring Security SAML extension (documenation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf) libraries, which uses XML based configuration.